# Python Multilevel Treemap

Tags: python, machine-learning

Treemap Mutlilevel plot of car make , type and count dataset  shown below. I found few  packages using plotly.express and matplotlib-extra. But it did not help.

I want to have a customized lables  in the format

Squarify does not support multilevel

```
#labels = [f'{make}\n{count}' for make, count in zip(car_cmt_df['Make'].tolist(), car_cmt_df['Type'].tolist())]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

|  | Make | Type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Audi | Convertible | 79 |
| 1 | Audi | Coupe | 210 V |
| 2 | Audi | Hatchback | 41 |
| 3 | Audi | Sedan | 216 |
| 4 | Audi | Wagon | 43 |
| 5 | BMW | Convertible | 162 |
| 6 | BMW | Coupe | 86 |
| 7 | BMW | SUV | 123 |
| 8 | BMW | Sedan | 118 |
| 9 | BMW | Wagon | 42 |
| 10 | Chevrolet | Convertible | 85 |
| 11 | Chevrolet | Coupe | 45 |
| 12 | Chevrolet | Crew Cab | 85 |
| 13 | Chevrolet | Extended Cab | 87 |
| 14 | Chevrolet | Regular Cab | 82 |
| 15 | Chevrolet | SS | 119 |
| 16 | Chevrolet | SUV | 81 |
| 17 | Chevrolet | Sedan | 171 |
| 18 | Chevrolet | Van | 65 |
| 19 | Chevrolet | Z06 | 38 |
| 20 | Chevrolet | ZR1 | 47 |
| 21 | Fisker | Sedan | 44 |
| 22 | HUMMER | Crew Cab | 83 |
| 23 | Ram | Minivan | 41 |
| 24 | Tesla | Sedan | 39 |

Please find image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got some resemblance with below code using plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
cnt = car_cmt_df.groupby(['Make', 'Type']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
# #labels = [f'{make}\n{count}' for make, count in zip(car_cmt_df['Make'].tolist(), car_cmt_df['Type'].tolist())]
# # fig = px.treemap(cnt, path=['Make', 'Type'])
# # fig.show()
px.treemap(cnt, path=['Make','Type'], values='Count',color='Make', color_continuous_scale='orrd')
```